# Power set in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Let X be any set and A = P(X) be the power set of X. Let x1,...,xn be distinct points in X and let α1, . . . , αn be positive real numbers. Show the measure on A.

I'm uncertain if  μ = α1δx1 + α2δx2 + · · · + αnδxn defines a measure on A and would really appreciate some insight into why this may be.

Comment: This is a very vague question. What should be the role of the $x_i$ and $\alpha_i$ in the measure on $\wp(X)$?

Comment: Let X be any set and A = P(X) be the power set of X. Let x1,...,xn be distinct points in X and let α1, . . . , αn be positive real numbers. I've been told I should derive something to look like μ = α1δx1 + α2δx2 + · · · + αnδxn defines a measure on A. @drhab

Comment: That information must be a part of the question (not a comment).

Comment: However I'm unsure if this is actually correct @drhab .

Comment: Okay I'll add it! I just wasn't sure as I didn't want to post something incorrect @drhab

Comment: Please use Mathjax!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x_i\in X$ and $\alpha_i\in[0,\infty)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\delta_{x_i}$ denotes a measure on $\sigma$-algebra $\wp(X)$.

The measure is prescribed by: $$B\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\delta_{x_i}(B)=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\mathsf1_B(x_i)$$

Comment: Ah I see. Then would I be correct in saying that A=P(X) is a probability measure if the αi 's add to 1?

Comment: Not $A=\wp(X)$ is a probability measure but indeed $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\delta_i$ is a probability measure iff $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$. This of course under the mentioned condition that $\alpha_i\geq0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Yes I understand, excuse the incorrect wording in my question ! @drhab